# Constructing Table iterators programmatically: how to avoid the non-list iterator error?

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

The following simple code of course works:

```
Table[n^2, {n, 3, 15, 2}]
(* Out: {9, 25, 49, 81, 121, 169, 225} *)
```

I would then like to construct the iterator programmatically. However, the following approach does not work:

```
d = {n, 3, 15}      (* Out: {n, 3, 15} *)
a = Append[d, 2]    (* Out: {n, 3, 15, 2} *)
Table[n^2, a]
```

> Error: Non-list iterator `a` at position 2 does not evaluate to a real numeric value.

How can I avoid that error?

Comment: You need to use `Evaluate`, for variable iterator lists. `d = {n, 3, 15}; a = Append[d, 2]; Table[n^2, Evaluate[a]]`